# Get values of checkbox in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `repeater` inner another `repeater` and this second one i have a list of `checkbox` and i need to get the value of the checked.

This is my front code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptPerfis" OnItemDataBound="ItemBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="mws-form-row">
            <ul class="mws-form-list inline" style="float: none; display: inline;">
                <li style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <%# rptNome(Container) %></li>
            </ul>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptUsers">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="mws-form-item radioPermissoes clearfix" style="float: none;">
                        <ul class="mws-form-list inline">
                            <li>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="<%# rptAdministradorNome(Container) %>" ID="checkUser" CssClass="<%# rptAdministradorPostClass(Container) %>" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <br />
        <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="fLnkSalvar" class="mws-ic-16 ic-disk" OnClick="fLnkSalvar_Click">Salvar</asp:LinkButton>
```

and this is how i fill this repeater:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listaAdm = Servicos.AdministradorMySql.ListarEmpresa(denuncia.Empresa).OrderByDescending(x => x.Nome).ToList();
    todosPerfis = Servicos.Perfil.ListarTodos().ToList();
    rptPerfis.DataSource = todosPerfis.Where(x => x.Ativo).OrderBy(x => x.Nome);
    rptPerfis.DataBind();

}

protected void ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {

        int idPerfil = ((Perfil)args.Item.DataItem).ID;
        Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)args.Item.FindControl("rptUsers");
        childRepeater.DataSource = listaAdm.Where(x => x.Perfil > 1 && x.Perfil == idPerfil).ToList();
        childRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}

    protected void fLnkSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Administrador usuario = new Administrador();
        usuario.Permissoes = new List<string>();

        // i need to get this values here to fill this `List<string>` and then save

        foreach (var x in usuario.Permissoes)
        {
            Servicos.Denuncia.InserirUsuarios(denuncia.ID, x);
        }
    }
```

I've no idea how can i get this values or if there another easier way without add in the list i think its better

Comment: At what point do you want to get the value of the repeater? Is there some specific event?

Comment: @mason it's just when i click on button save, i already have the event of the button just don't know how get the checked ones

Comment: In that case, you should add the event handler for the button click to your question, and put a comment inside the body of that method saying that's where you want to get the checkbox values. Makes it easier for whoever is answering your question to understand when you want this to happen, and gives them a starting point to build their code off of. The easier you can make it to answer your question, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use FindControl on multiple levels. First the correct Item in the parent Repeater, then find the CheckBox in the correct Item of the child Repeater.

```
var cb = ((Repeater)rptPerfis.Items[i].FindControl("rptUsers")).Items[j].FindControl("checkUser") as CheckBox;
```

PS you need to wrap the code in `Page_Load` in an `IsPostBack` check or you will never retrieve the correct checkbox state in a PostBack.